# ReadFile on standard input crashes on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Trying to read standard input with ReadFile works on Windows 8+ but crashes on Windows 7.

```
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    char c[1];
    HANDLE in = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    ReadFile(in, c, 1, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000770f5803 in VerifyConsoleIoHandle () from C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
```

on Windows 7

Comment: Your code is broken, as is clear from the documentation

Comment: I'd disagree about the documentation being "clear" when it describes lpNumberOfBytesRead as _in_opt. I'm just trying to document a common pitfall.

Comment: *This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is not NULL.* How could that be more clear?

Answer (score 2):

[the lpNumberOfBytesRead argument is required, unless the ReadFile will complete asynchronously (the file/device was opened with the correct flags and lpOverlapped is provided)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20161026-00/?p=94585)

On Windows 8 and later this parameter is checked for NULL before writing (effectively making it optional) but this is not documented anywhere.

Reading standard input without checking the number of bytes read is a bad idea anyway, since the number of bytes read could be less than requested (or even 0) if input is redirected to a pipe.